# String to String array? java

Tags: java, arrays, string

Have a bunch of urls separated by space in a string:

```
String urls =

"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8xjfdGErgUc/maxresdefault.jpg https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9xber0p1bTw/maxresdefault.jpg https://yt3.ggpht.com/-fG6iPki4sFY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/2Sbu6OjrBik/s900-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg https://yt3.ggpht.com/-YZyzwE3a30c/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/16qPbHiYJmc/s900-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg https://yt3.ggpht.com/-EYlRar9RsEY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/JPQTc68e_x4/s900-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg https://i.ytimg.com/vi/VttZwjV38H0/maxresdefault.jpg https://yt3.ggpht.com/-7qUTA41fVxA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ZtK1pGLa4vw/s900-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KfQBdRcgizc/maxresdefault.jpg https://yt3.ggpht.com/-VGI9T-Sm5xg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AtC93A0H3AQ/s900-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aRkceYdlkTo/maxresdefault.jpg"
```

Attempt at converting to String array produces unexpected output?

```
String[] urlAry = urls.split(" ");
```

output

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@1e5746c0
```

Comment: You didn't specify a language. Is this Java?

Comment: The code you posted is not outputting anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
Arrays.toString(Object[] arr)
```

This will print a string representation of the Objects in the array rather than a String representation of the Array itself.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
String urls = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8xjfdGErgUc/maxresdefault.jpg https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9xber0p1bTw/maxresdefault.jpg https://yt3.ggpht.com/-fG6iPki4sFY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/2Sbu6OjrBik/s900-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg https://yt3.ggpht.com/-YZyzwE3a30c/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/16qPbHiYJmc/s900-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg https://yt3.ggpht.com/-EYlRar9RsEY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/JPQTc68e_x4/s900-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg https://i.ytimg.com/vi/VttZwjV38H0/maxresdefault.jpg https://yt3.ggpht.com/-7qUTA41fVxA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ZtK1pGLa4vw/s900-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KfQBdRcgizc/maxresdefault.jpg https://yt3.ggpht.com/-VGI9T-Sm5xg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AtC93A0H3AQ/s900-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aRkceYdlkTo/maxresdefault.jpg";
            String[] urlAry = urls.split(" ");
            for (String url : urlAry) {
                System.out.println(url);
            }
```

Output:

```
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8xjfdGErgUc/maxresdefault.jpg
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9xber0p1bTw/maxresdefault.jpg
https://yt3.ggpht.com/-fG6iPki4sFY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/2Sbu6OjrBik/s900-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg
https://yt3.ggpht.com/-YZyzwE3a30c/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/16qPbHiYJmc/s900-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg
https://yt3.ggpht.com/-EYlRar9RsEY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/JPQTc68e_x4/s900-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/VttZwjV38H0/maxresdefault.jpg
https://yt3.ggpht.com/-7qUTA41fVxA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ZtK1pGLa4vw/s900-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KfQBdRcgizc/maxresdefault.jpg
https://yt3.ggpht.com/-VGI9T-Sm5xg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AtC93A0H3AQ/s900-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aRkceYdlkTo/maxresdefault.jpg
```